# osm2pgsql has stopped working

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I want to import osm planet-131113.osm.pbf whit osm2pgsql.
But whent it proccessing relation the window throw and say "osm2pgsql has stopped working" and then proccess killed.What is the problem?

My hardware is:

Cpu:intel xeon E5-2620.

Ram:24GB

Mainbord:supermico x9dr3-f-o

HDD:seagate 2tb barracuda

My os:

windows server 2008 R2

and Postgresql9.3 with postgis2.1 bundle

Postgresql config:

```
 effective-chache-size=28GB
 shared_buffers 2GB
 maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
 work-mem=512MB
 checkpoint_segments = 100
 chekpoint_completion-target=0.9
 autovacuum = off
 fsync=off
 synchronous-commit=off
 full-page-writes=off
```

and osm2pgsql command:
F:\OSM\x64>osm2pgsql -d OSMPlanet -s -S default.style -C 16000 -U postgres -r pbf -k -v --number-processes 12  planet-131113.osm.pbf
osm2pgsql SVN version af61cae663 (64bit id space)

release notes: 'Windows version built by Dominik Perpeet (http://www.customdebug
.com/osm2pgsql/index.html)'

WARNING: osm2pgsql was compiled without fork, only using one process!

Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)

Setting up table: planet_osm_point

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping

Setting up table: planet_osm_line

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line" does not exist, skipping

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line_tmp" does not exist, skipping

Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon" does not exist, skipping

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon_tmp" does not exist, skipping

Setting up table: planet_osm_roads

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads" does not exist, skipping

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads_tmp" does not exist, skipping

Allocating memory for sparse node cache

Node-cache: cache=16000MB, maxblocks=2048001*zd, allocation method=8192

Mid: pgsql, scale=100 cache=16000

Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_nodes" does not exist, skipping

Setting up table: planet_osm_ways

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_ways" does not exist, skipping

Setting up table: planet_osm_rels

NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_rels" does not exist, skipping

Reading in file: planet-131113.osm.pbf

Processing: Node(2084251k 142.6k/s) Way(204149k 0.84k/s) Relation(95360 5.64/s)

postgresql log:

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST ERROR:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST CONTEXT:  COPY planet_osm_nodes, line 1

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST STATEMENT:  COPY planet_osm_nodes FROM STDIN;

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST ERROR:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST CONTEXT:  COPY planet_osm_rels, line 1

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST STATEMENT:  COPY planet_osm_rels FROM STDIN;

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST LOG:  could not send data to client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST STATEMENT:  COPY planet_osm_ways FROM STDIN;

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST LOG:  could not send data to client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST STATEMENT:  COPY planet_osm_nodes FROM STDIN;

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST LOG:  could not send data to client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST STATEMENT:  COPY planet_osm_rels FROM STDIN;

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST FATAL:  connection to client lost

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST FATAL:  connection to client lost

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST FATAL:  connection to client lost

2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST FATAL:  connection to client lost

2013-12-09 00:48:53 PST LOG:  received fast shutdown request

2013-12-09 00:48:53 PST LOG:  aborting any active transactions

2013-12-09 00:48:53 PST LOG:  shutting down

2013-12-09 00:48:53 PST LOG:  database system is shut down

Comment: Check (1) your PostgreSQL logs and see if it reports any errors before the client dies. Then (2) check memory usage of osm2pgsql while it's running. If there's nothing in #1 and #2 stays under control then it could be a bug, but check for errors and out-of-memory problems first.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I check Postgresql log and find this. **2013-12-09 00:46:19 PST FATAL:  connection to client lost**. what is the problem?

Comment: The client (osm2pgsql) died without closing the connection. OK - if there's nothing else then we know the problem is within osm2pgsql.

Comment: What should I can do for this?

Comment: Well, start by checking the memory usage, as I suggested. Then, see if there is a "verbose" or "debug" option you can set with osm2pgsql. I do know there is an option to reduce the memory used.